# cannot find symbol problem with try-catch

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, validation

hey guys the compiler keeps giving me a cannot find symbol for the try-catch here..
i'm trying to scan for a int but i have to user input error check for other stuff and yet i cant seem to be able to catch the exception..

```
try
 {
 starid = sc.nextInt();
 }catch(InputMismatchException e)
  {
  System.out.println("Error in input!!");
  }
```

Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: Posting the exact error message would be really useful. Oh, and it wouldn't hurt to tell us what type `sc` is. From your code, we can only guess. Telling us these bits of information would net you an answer much faster.

Comment: while (sc.hasNext()) {
      if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        starid  = sc.nextInt();
      }
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have the right import for `InputMismatchException`, e.g.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
```

or

```
import java.util.*;
```

If you could post the *exact* error message, that would be helpful.

Comment: haha the reply was so fast they kept saying i needed to wait a min amt of time... no idea y but now its accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to tell, from seven lines of code.

Other than what Jon said, you might not have initialized `starid` (e.g. `int starid  = null ;`). Please post the exception stack or full error description.